# custom output in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I have code which generates a time in zulu. Now I want it to have multiple output options, but the easy way. Is there a quicker way to do this:

```
function zuluTime(format) {
    if(!format) { return false; }

    format      = format.toLowerCase();
    zuluDate    = new Date();

    zuluHour    = zuluDate.getUTCHours();
    zuluMin     = zuluDate.getUTCMinutes();
    zuluSec     = zuluDate.getUTCSeconds();

    zuluHour    = (zuluHour <= 9) ? '0'+zuluHour : zuluHour;
    zuluMin     = (zuluMin  <= 9) ? '0'+zuluMin  : zuluMin;
    zuluSec     = (zuluSec  <= 9) ? '0'+zuluSec  : zuluSec;
    zuluTenths  = Math.floor((zuluSec / 60) * 10)
    zulu        = '<span>Z</span';

    if(format == 'hhmmss')  { time = (zuluHour+':'+zuluMin+':'+zuluSec+zulu);           }
    if(format == 'hhmm')    { time = (zuluHour+''+zuluMin+zulu);                        }
    if(format == 'hhmm.s')  { time = (zuluHour+''+zuluMin+'.'+zuluTenths+''+zulu);      }

    return time;
}
```

Is it possible to make some function which recognizes if the format contains hh.s for example without having to if else?

Comment: Why not just use JS's date formatting? Or convert your format string to JS's?

Comment: Use a _RegExp_ in `String.prototype.replace` with a _function_ as the second arg

Comment: Is `hhmmss` meant to be equal to `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: The way of handling time yourself lies madness. If you're not under native JS requirements, I would absolutely recommend using datejs, momentjs, or another library for date management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *RegExp* in [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a function as the second *argument*

```
var re = /hh|mm|ss|s/g,
        map = {
        hh: zuluHour,
        mm: zuluMin,
        ss: zuluSec,
        s: zuluTenths
    };
function replacor($0) {
    if ($0 in map)
        return map[$0];
    return $0;
}

time = format.replace(re, replacor);
```

This method is easily expanded to permit more variables and will work on any *"formatting"*, e.g. `Thh:mm:ssZ` will become `T16:31:58Z`, even though you didn't teach it with a list what to do for that specific format.

If `hhmmss` is meant to be equal to `hh:mm:ss` you will need to apply this transformation to `format` first.